# Use of Sync Framework with WCF Data services

Tags: synchronization, wcf-data-services, microsoft-sync-framework

I have both SQL Server 2008 R2 edition on both Server and Client side. And I am using two WCF Data service to connect to them via Entity Framework. I wanted to sync these two Db using sync framework, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sync Framework doesnt integrate with EF or WCF Data Service. If you use Sync Framework, it will need to establish direct connections to the databases directly outside EF and WCF Data Service.

see: Tutorial: [Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. You can setup a synchronisation between to provider on EF. This is theorical. I'm working on iy by implementing a FullEnumerationSimpleSyncProvider. Everything works fine except error handling.

For integration with WCF go and have a look here: [WCF 4.0 & Sync Framework 2.0 & Entity Framework 4.0 & ASP.NET MVC 2.0 & auto generated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859522/wcf-4-0-sync-framework-2-0-entity-framework-4-0-asp-net-mvc-2-0-auto-gen)